# Regex to match item in csv string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that's a csv of 5-6 digit numbers.
I.e.
'12345,67890,555555'. There can also be spaces in before/after a number. So ' 123456 , 12345,22222'.

I was initially doing my regex match of 
`Trying to see in '12345' is in a csv

```
 const csv = '12345,67890,555555';
   const regex = /12345/
   regex.test(csv);
```

`

But I'm seeing this introduces false positive of if another character can exist before the test. I.e. It's also matching on '012345', etc.

What's the best way to search here? I'm doing my matches with regex matches with `Mongo` DB filters btw

Comment: Wrap word boundary around your number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just adjust your regex to use anchors.  Anchors restrict where your match can be, without matching any additional characters.  In this case, I believe you need to anchor to a word boundary on both sides, which will require that the character on either side of `12345` is not a "word character" (Any alphanumeric character or an underscore).  This means it could be next to a comma, space, beginning of line, or end of line in your case.  The token for a word boundary is `\b`.  This makes your regex: `const regex = /\b12345\b/`.

You can also avoid using regex by writing your own `test()` function.  Assuming you know that your CSV is comma-delimited, you can split the string by commas, store the result in an array, and then loop through that array, checking if each element is equal to the string you're looking for.  This could be implemented like so:

```js
function test(needle, haystack) {
    let arr = haystack.split(",");

    for (let str of arr) {
        if (str === needle) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to include this in the JS `RegExp` constructor? So rn, I have `new RegExp(number);` I'd like to add the word boundaries to both sides on the constructor

Comment: Any alternative to using regex? Seems to be very slow when operating on tons of values.

Comment: @user2402616 I've added an alternative to regex, but note that it may or may not be any faster than the regex was.  JS regex is just a standard, so browsers can implement it any way they choose.

Comment: Regex seems to be way faster than using split/search approach. Hm.. I'm looking into paralleljs to see if I can take advantage of that. Could be overkill, but seems interesting

Comment: @user2402616 Yeah, I thought that might be the case.  The implementation I gave is a linear search, but regex probably implements it with a faster search method.  You can look for faster search methods on google, but my guess is, you're not going to find anything faster than whatever the regex implementation is using.  I'm not familiar with paralleljs, but a large amount of data like this is typically a prime situation for concurrency, so you're likely on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var csv = '12345,67890,555555';
var csv2 = '012345,67890,555555';
var regex = /\b12345\b/;
console.log(regex.test(csv)); //true
console.log(regex.test(csv2)); //false
```

\b is the word boundary.